# pod install Mac OS terminal iOS

Tags: ios, macos, terminal, cocoapods

everything was fine, I always did a 'pod install' inside project in terminal, and everything was fine.
But now I have this error.
I have tried uninstalling cocoapods and reinstalling them with no success.
I also removed 'cocoapods trunk' and reinstalled.
removed the gem. It didn't solve the problem.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u1PiX.png)

Full error:

```
[!] CDN: trunk URL couldn't be downloaded: https://cdn.cocoapods.org/CocoaPods-version.yml Response: 403 <!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if lt IE 7]> <html class="no-js ie6 oldie" lang="en-US"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>    <html class="no-js ie7 oldie" lang="en-US"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>    <html class="no-js ie8 oldie" lang="en-US"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <html class="no-js" lang="en-US"> <!--<![endif]-->
<head>
<title>Attention Required! | Cloudflare</title>
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge" />
<meta name="robots" content="noindex, nofollow" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1" />
<link rel="stylesheet" id="cf_styles-css" href="/cdn-cgi/styles/cf.errors.css" />
<!--[if lt IE 9]><link rel="stylesheet" id='cf_styles-ie-css' href="/cdn-cgi/styles/cf.errors.ie.css" /><![endif]-->
<style>body{margin:0;padding:0}</style>


<!--[if gte IE 10]><!-->
<script>
  if (!navigator.cookieEnabled) {
    window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
      var cookieEl = document.getElementById('cookie-alert');
      cookieEl.style.display = 'block';
    })
  }
</script>
<!--<![endif]-->


</head>
<body>
  <div id="cf-wrapper">
    <div class="cf-alert cf-alert-error cf-cookie-error" id="cookie-alert" data-translate="enable_cookies">Please enable cookies.</div>
    <div id="cf-error-details" class="cf-error-details-wrapper">
      <div class="cf-wrapper cf-header cf-error-overview">
        <h1 data-translate="block_headline">Sorry, you have been blocked</h1>
        <h2 class="cf-subheadline"><span data-translate="unable_to_access">You are unable to access</span> cocoapods.org</h2>
      </div><!-- /.header -->

      <div class="cf-section cf-highlight">
        <div class="cf-wrapper">
          <div class="cf-screenshot-container cf-screenshot-full">
            
              <span class="cf-no-screenshot error"></span>
            
          </div>
        </div>
      </div><!-- /.captcha-container -->

      <div class="cf-section cf-wrapper">
        <div class="cf-columns two">
          <div class="cf-column">
            <h2 data-translate="blocked_why_headline">Why have I been blocked?</h2>

            <p data-translate="blocked_why_detail">This website is using a security service to protect itself from online attacks. The action you just performed triggered the security solution. There are several actions that could trigger this block including submitting a certain word or phrase, a SQL command or malformed data.</p>
          </div>

          <div class="cf-column">
            <h2 data-translate="blocked_resolve_headline">What can I do to resolve this?</h2>

            <p data-translate="blocked_resolve_detail">You can email the site owner to let them know you were blocked. Please include what you were doing when this page came up and the Cloudflare Ray ID found at the bottom of this page.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div><!-- /.section -->

      <div class="cf-error-footer cf-wrapper w-240 lg:w-full py-10 sm:py-4 sm:px-8 mx-auto text-center sm:text-left border-solid border-0 border-t border-gray-300">
  <p class="text-13">
    <span class="cf-footer-item sm:block sm:mb-1">Cloudflare Ray ID: <strong class="font-semibold">709b4775bf6f2481</strong></span>
    <span class="cf-footer-separator sm:hidden">&bull;</span>
    <span class="cf-footer-item sm:block sm:mb-1"><span>Your IP</span>: 46.118.2.19</span>
    <span class="cf-footer-separator sm:hidden">&bull;</span>
    <span class="cf-footer-item sm:block sm:mb-1"><span>Performance &amp; security by</span> <a rel="noopener noreferrer" href="https://www.cloudflare.com/5xx-error-landing" id="brand_link" target="_blank">Cloudflare</a></span>
    
  </p>
</div><!-- /.error-footer -->


    </div><!-- /#cf-error-details -->
  </div><!-- /#cf-wrapper -->

  <script>
  window._cf_translation = {};
  
  
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I don't have an answer for you.  I was just coming here to ask exactly the same question.  I'm guessing this is potentially some error on the CocoaPods side.  :/

Comment: Really? You also got this error today, but before that everything was fine?

Comment: Yup.  Other people on my project in the same codebase are not having the error though.  I first saw it upon trying to add a new dependency, but even removing that, switching branches, etc., nothing seems to get it to go away.

Comment: I can tell you a temporary solution.
 
In terminal:

pod repo remove trunk

In Podfile:

source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'

# source 'https://cdn.cocoapods.org/'

then make pod install

Comment: but if you find a normal solution - write here)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CDN: trunk URL couldn't be downloaded: https://cdn.cocoapods.org/CocoaPods-version.yml Response: 403](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72200847/cdn-trunk-url-couldnt-be-downloaded-https-cdn-cocoapods-org-cocoapods-versi)

Comment: No, did u see my answer below?

Answer (score 0):

In terminal:

First step:

```
pod repo remove trunk
```

Second step:

```
git clone --depth 1 git@github.com:CocoaPods/Specs.git
```

NOT: clone --depth 1 git@github.com:/CocoaPods/Specs.git

You should do it without "/" before Cocoapods

Then go to project libary and make

```
'pod install'
```